# regex to isolate specific part of a in-line style from string

Tags: php

I have the following string ($str) `#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6`

One thing to consider is **stop-opacity** maybe buried in the string, the sample string above is just an example. Below are some alternate example positioning of the string:

```
stop-opacity:0.6;#FFFFFF;
#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6;stop-color:#FFFFFF;
```

I am trying to extract stop-opacity and its value into a separate array (e.g. $arr) `array("type"=>"stop-opacity","value"=>"0.6")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/purple-resonance-7wjd-m8bfk) so you can view and play with the code used for this answer.

The regex below is able to extract the string you need:

```
stop-opacity         # Find stop-opacity within the string
  \s*                # Match zero or more whitespace characters
     :               # Match the : character
      \s*            # Match zero or more whitespace characters
         (           # Start a capture group
          [0-9\.]+   # Match characters 0-9 and . one or more times
                  )  # End the capture group
```

I have implemented the regex above into a simple PHP script below which shows its usage along with some testing, it also includes your requirements as stated in the question:

```
<?php

function getStopOpacity(string $line) {
    preg_match('/stop-opacity\s*:\s*([0-9\.]+)/', $line, $matches);

    return [
        'type' => 'stop-opacity',
        'value' => $matches[1] ?? null
    ];
}

$tests = [
    "#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6",
    "stop-opacity:0.6;#FFFFFF;",
    "#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6;stop-color:#FFFFFF;",
    "#FFFFFF;stop-opacity  :      0.6  ;stop-color:#FFFFFF;"
];

foreach($tests as $test) {
    $result = getStopOpacity($test);

    echo $result['type'] . ": " . $result['value'] . "\n";
}
```

The above outputs:

```
stop-opacity: 0.6
stop-opacity: 0.6
stop-opacity: 0.6
stop-opacity: 0.6
```

---

I have updated the answer in response to the comment provided by OP.

The regex has been adjusted so that it can capture many different attribute values within a string:

```
stop-color          # Find stop-color within the string (but this can be changed to any attribute)
  \s*               # Match zero or more whitespace characters
     :              # Match the : character
      \s*           # Match zero or more whitespace characters
         (          # Start a capture group
          .+?       # Match any character (non-greedy)
             )      # End the capture group
              \s*   # Match zero or more whitespace characters
                 ;  # Match the ; character
```

**There is a caveat with the regex above, the attribute value must have a `;` character after it.**

I have created a new [sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/round-bush-j7do-znasd) so you can review the code.

The function has been updated to accept an attribute as a parameter, allowing you to extract many different key/value pairs from the string:

```
<?php

function getAttributeValue(string $attribute, string $line) {
    preg_match("/$attribute\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*;/", $line, $matches);

    return [
        'type' => $attribute,
        'value' => $matches[1] ?? null
    ];
}

$tests = [
    "#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6;",
    "stop-opacity:0.6;#FFFFFF;",
    "#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6;stop-color:#FFFFFF;",
    "#FFFFFF;stop-opacity  :      0.6  ;stop-color:red;"
];

foreach($tests as $test) {
    $result = getAttributeValue("stop-opacity", $test);

    echo $result['type'] . ": " . $result['value'] . "\n";
}

$tests = [
    "#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.6;stop-color:#FFFFFF;",
    "#FFFFFF;stop-opacity  :      0.6  ;stop-color:red;"
];

foreach($tests as $test) {
    $result = getAttributeValue("stop-color", $test);

    echo $result['type'] . ": " . $result['value'] . "\n";
}
```

The above outputs:

```
stop-opacity: 0.6
stop-opacity: 0.6
stop-opacity: 0.6
stop-opacity: 0.6
stop-color: #FFFFFF
stop-color: red
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I would be grateful for a similar regex to capture the same for stop-color key and value. The stop-color attribute would usually looks like this `stop-color:#FFFFFF` - same deal it may be at any position in the string. The only complication is the hex color code may not be guaranteed to be 6 chars long (FFFFFF) it may be a word value as well like "red" or "black" or "fff" etc.. If stop-color is at the beginning or middle of then it's value will end with `;`.

Comment: i just double checked the latest regex and it seems to only capture stop-color values ending in `;`. Are we able to make it flexible as the value may not end with semi-column if its the only value or the last attribute in the string. If that's too complicated i can settle with having a separate function for stop-color and stop-opacity.